# React app build is failing when building a docker image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-desktop, windows-11

I am trying to dockerize a react application, but `npm run build` layer is failing and giving this error:
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app/app-v2

COPY .npmrc ./

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:qa

RUN rm -r node_modules

# CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:qa"]
```

I'm facing error on build layer.

```
 => ERROR [7/8] RUN npm run build:qa                                                                                     292.8s 
------
 > [7/8] RUN npm run build:qa:
#11 3.687 
#11 3.687 > react-app@0.1.0 build:qa
#11 3.687 > env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts build
#11 3.687 
#11 12.59 Creating an optimized production build...
#11 291.6 The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build:qa]: exit code: 1
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWLo.png)

I'm using node v16 and npm v8, Docker Desktop, Windows 11 64

Comment: Did you check the memory usage during the build process? As the error suggests, you might've run out of memory.

Comment: How can I check the memory usage?

Comment: You can check in task manager what the memory usage is.

Comment: @AbhishekS I am now building a image on linux server which has 8gb of memory still same issue, and as far I researched docker uses all the available memory of host system

Comment: Set Environmental variable:
`ENV TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max_old_space_size=4096"`

Comment: @AbhishekS I already did this but no luck `react-scripts --max-old-space-size=4096 build`

Comment: I think this is the right way to use it: `node --max-old-space-size=250 \`which npm\` some_npm_command`

Comment: I face the memory issue before in development environment, at that time we uses this and issue resolved, that is the right way @AbhishekS

Comment: Then updating that as the answer. Please accept the same as answer @MohammadShawerKhandariya

Comment: @AbhishekS development environment means by running `npm start` script not with `npm run build` script, I tried this `react-scripts --max-old-space-size=4096 build` before your comment already but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems your server does not have enough system memory to build your project.
In general, I would recommend 1GB memory on your vps or if using a windows OS then it depends on the version. It would be helpful to provide the amount of memory available on your host.
Some reference on docker system requirements: [Docker requirements](https://forums.docker.com/t/minimum-hardware-requirement-to-run-docker/28072)

Comment: I am using docker desktop version 4.12.0 on windows